# ActiveMQ Artemis ActiveMQSecurityManager4 verify ClientID/Subscription

Tags: activemq-artemis

Currently Artemis the has ActiveMQSecurityManager4. It gives a lot of control when using the following method:

```
/**
* Determine whether the given user is valid and whether they have
* the correct role for the given destination address.
*
* This method is called instead of
* {@link ActiveMQSecurityManager#validateUserAndRole(String, String, Set, CheckType)}.
*
* @param user       the user
* @param password   the user's password
* @param roles      the user's roles
* @param checkType  which permission to validate
* @param address    the address for which to perform authorization
* @param remotingConnection the user's connection
* @param securityDomain the name of the JAAS security domain to use (can be null)
* @return the name of the validated user or null if the user isn't validated
*/
String validateUserAndRole(String user,
                          String password,
                          Set<Role> roles,
                          CheckType checkType,
                          String address,
                          RemotingConnection remotingConnection,
                          String securityDomain);
```

When a client connects and tries to create a subscription is there a way to know what is his ClientID/Subscription Name? (CheckType=CREATE_DURABLE_QUEUE  over address="org.activemq.premium.news" )

I want to have control who is allowed to subscribe a given address (TOPIC) and guarantee that a subscription belongs to the initial (authenticated) subscriber.

EDIT 1:

The caller method has the queue (clientID+subs name) but I don't think It can be extended.

```
/**
* The ActiveMQ Artemis SecurityStore implementation
*/
public class SecurityStoreImpl implements SecurityStore, HierarchicalRepositoryChangeListener {

...

@Override
public void check(final SimpleString address,
                  final SimpleString queue,  //exactly what I was looking for
                  final CheckType checkType,
                  final SecurityAuth session) throws Exception {
...
```

EDIT 2:

Scenario

I have Bob (user:bob, pass: bob) and Alice (user:Alice, pass:Alice) and each one will create their connection to the broker to subscribe let's say address="org.activemq.premium.news". So far I can block one of them from reaching the address, which is not bad. Now I want both to subscribe (each one will have a queue) but I want to make sure the Bob's subscription is named "bob" and Alice's subscription is named "alice". I don't want that if Alice subscribes first it uses "bob" as subscription name. Also not sure if the spec guaranties that after the initial subscription from Bob, if he is not connected Alice cannot use his subscription name to consume his messages - i.e. subscription queue is bound to that user.

Comment: What kind of clients/protocols are you using?

Comment: I'm using org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:2.12.0, which I think it uses the CORE protocol. For now I just need JMS 2.0. Would be nice to support AMQP and STOMP as well.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do or why (despite your explanation), but if you can't do what you want by implementing a security manager then maybe you can do what you by via a [broker plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html).

Comment: I think the security manager is what I need, not sure which broker plugin I should have a look to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Added a scenario. Maybe my idea is dumb but I want to have specific subscription names per user (system). As I said the "final SimpleString queue" information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial requirement is now possible due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2886 changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do was already addressed via [ARTEMIS-592](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-592). You just need to concatenate the address and queue name with a `.` character in your related `security-setting` in `broker.xml`. Be sure to put the users which should be isolated in different groups.

To be clear, you don't need to implement a security manager or plugin or anything like that. You should be able to take care of everything you need just with configuration.

Comment: Sounds like what I need, so it's not crazy after all :) I'll have a look during the weekend as I'm not sure where to concatenate it. On the validateUserAndRole method can't so I assume it has to be done in a early phase so when it reach the validateUserAndRole there's already the address+queue (clientID+subsName).

Comment: I'm doing authentication with OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0) that's why I've created the custom security manager. Probably will use User Managed Access 2.0 for authorization on each address.

Comment: Also, could you not integrate with OpenID Connect via a JAAS login module?

Comment: No and yes. Currently on the custom security manager I use your example where I do the OAuth2 Client Credentials flow and if it fails I delegate to the ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager. It might be possible to create a JAAS Login module as suggest on https://medium.com/@joelicious/extending-artemis-security-with-oauth2-7fd9b3dffe3 , but the custom security manager sounded better. ActiveMQSecurityManager4 is perfect just misses the queue name as a parameter, that is available on the caller method. Maybe ActiveMQSecurityManager5 will have it.

Comment: Are you configuring authorization via `security-settings` in `broker.xml`? If not, did you create an implementation of `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.SecuritySettingPlugin`? Are you developing `ActiveMQSecurityManager5`?

Comment: ActiveMQSecurityManager5? no way...I leave that for the experts ;) was just proposing that queue name could be added as parameter. Not sure how org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.SecuritySettingPlugin can help.

Comment: Btw I probably don't have enough skills on JAAS, that's why I can't understand how a JAAS login module can help. We'll for the authentication part probably, but for the fine grained authorization maybe the org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.SecuritySettingPlugin can help, but so far I have no clue how to combine them both to achieve what I want.

Comment: Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2861 as I think org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.SecuritySettingPlugin will not do the trick. The AuthZ is role based and I need to have fine grain control with https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_overview_terminology.

Comment: I commented on ARTEMIS-2861. With regards to `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.SecuritySettingPlugin`, I was simply suggesting you implement it if you weren't going to configure your `security-settings` in `broker.xml`. I mentioned that previously but you never indicated if that was your plan or not.

Comment: My idea was to avoid the security-settings in the broker.xml. I'll have a look on the ARTEMIS-2861 comment

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid `security-settings` in `broker.xml` you don't really have any other choice than to implement `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.SecuritySettingPlugin`.